# How to make page width equal to screen width in Opera Mobile, iOS, Android etc

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, html, css

Such browsers as Opera Mobile, iOS browser, Android browser (last two use webkit engine) emulate lager device's screen, than it is. For example: real device's screen width is 480px, but Opera Mobile shows the page, like the screen is 850px width.

How i can prevent such browsers from emulating larger device's screen size, and make them to display web page as wide, as real device's screen?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`<meta name="viewport" />`](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/09/combining_meta.html)

Comment: I've already tried it, but the page layout still doesn't fit the screen, it looks better than without this tag, but it is half wider, than the screen (under Opera Mobile). `document.documentElement.clientWidth` shows vendor-specified screen width, when I use this tag. I've also tried [Opera analog CSS property](http://people.opera.com/rune/TR/css-viewport/), but it changed nothing (I'm not sure, I anderstood it and used correctly).

Answer (score 0):

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width;" />` in the head should set the viewport to the device width

Comment: I've already told, I'd tried it before. Look the explanation in the comment in the other answer.

Comment: this is different from the previous answer, it has a content tag. Did you insert this as well? edit: try adding `initial-scale = 1.0` at the end of wdth

Comment: Yes, I used `content="width=device-width`, and `initial-scale = 1.0` I also tried, but nothig changed. Please look up [here](http://timetable.raj.fvds.ru/m/), may be you'll find the reason.

Comment: they should have semicolons on the end not comas